# Avoid C++ object files from being added to Ctags tags file

Tags: c++, vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I had used the following command to generate my `tags` file to be used by `vim` in a C++ project:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iamS --extra=+fq --language-force=C++ /usr/include /home/user/audioprism/lib/essentia/ --exclude=.git --exclude=/home/user/audioprism/lib/essentia/src/examples -f /home/user/audioprism/tags
```

In a certain case I see the following:

```
# pri kind tag               file
> 1 F   v    Pool              
/home/user/audioprism/lib/essentia/bui...ia/streaming/algorithms/poolstorage.cpp.1.o               
/
  2 F   c    Pool              /home/user/audioprism/lib/essentia/src/essentia/pool.h
           namespace:essentia
           class Pool {
  3 F   v    Pool              
/home/user/audioprism/lib/essentia/src/examples/tutorial/example_onsetdetection.py
           from essentia import Pool, array
```

So, a `:ta` or `<Ctrl>+]` takes me to `poolstorage.cpp.1.o`, being the first entry. But how to avoid object files being added. Since the whole purpose is to navigate through the source code, I would like to avoid this situation. Tried the flag `--exclude=*.o` but that didn't help either.

How can I stop the object files from being added to `tags` file?

Comment: It looks like you have a separate build directory. Can't you pass that to `--exclude`?

Comment: If I do that, only the third entry is available. The actual definition in the second entry `pool.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `--langage-force`? My experiments with [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags) and my everyday work on C++ projects taught me that ex-ctags and universal-ctags are already able to sort out C++ files on their own based on the extension. I may use this parameter when running ctags on a temporary (extension-less) file where I've dumped the content of the current buffer. I don't need it otherwise to parse normal C++ files. We may also need it to parse the extension-less header files from the C++ standard  library. I highly doubt this is what you are doing.

Eventually, we can simply restrict the analysis to specific languages instead. Its the `--languages=` option with Universal Ctags (I don't remember what it is (/was) with the deprecated Exhuberant Ctags. I'd have to delve into the code of my `lh#tags#add_indexed_ft()` (vimscript) function. But honestly, if you're using ex-ctags, migrated to universal-ctags, in particular if you work with C++).

Using this option would also prevent ctags from parsing Python files as if they where C++ files. And you could also ask Python files to be parsed, or not.

Comment: So, if I switch to `universal-ctags`, I can remove `--language-force=C++` and run the same command right? And the above issue will be solved?

Comment: Remove `--language-force` in all cases. Use `--languages=C++`  instead. IIRC, it should be supported with ex-ctags as well, but I'm not sure. Now universal-ctags is maintained. This means it will be much better at understanding C++ than a project stopped in 2009. C++ has seen quite a few new standards since then. 2020 standard has been approved just a few days ago.